# Building a ruby script with Ocra for cross platform uses but i get the 'relative_path_form' with a stacktrace

Tags: ruby, ocra

I'm trying to build a .exe to execute my script on Windows without any ruby installation.
I'm using Ocra for that but i have a stack trace.

Also note that there are two files that runs the whole sc and that I use currently RVM and I didn't do any sudo gem install since I use RVM.

Gems used in the first file :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'colorize'
require 'colorized_string'
```

Gems used in the second file :

```
require 'libnotify'
require './firstfile'
require 'os'
require 'twilio-ruby'
```

Here is what Ocra gives me:

```
>ocra --output test.exe firstfile.rb secondfile.rb
/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/ocra-1.3.6/bin/ocra:41:in `relative_path_from': undefined method `path' for "/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global":String (NoMethodError)
from /home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/ocra-1.3.6/bin/ocra:779:in `block in build_exe'
from /home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/ocra-1.3.6/bin/ocra:762:in `each'
from /home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/ocra-1.3.6/bin/ocra:762:in `build_exe'
from /home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/ocra-1.3.6/bin/ocra:1177:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Here is more info about my rvm and my ruby version it's the exact output of 'rvm info'

```
  system:
uname:       "Linux xxxx 4.7.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Aug 17 08:13:35 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
system:      "arch/libc-2.24/x86_64"
bash:        "/usr/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.3.46(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)"
zsh:         " => not installed"



rvm:
version:      "rvm 1.27.0 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
updated:      "1 day 23 hours 44 minutes 51 seconds ago"
path:         "/home/xxxx/.rvm"



ruby:
interpreter:  "ruby"
version:      "2.4.0dev"
date:         "2016-05-20"
platform:     "x86_64-linux"
patchlevel:   "2016-05-20 trunk 55077"
full_version: "ruby 2.4.0dev (2016-05-20 trunk 55077) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
gem:          "/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head"
ruby:         "not set"

  binaries:
ruby:         "/home/xxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/ruby"
irb:          "/home/xxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/irb"
gem:          "/home/xxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/gem"
rake:         "/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin/rake"

  environment:
PATH:         "/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/bin:/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global/bin:/home/xxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin:/home/xxxx/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin"
GEM_HOME:     "/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head"
GEM_PATH:     "/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head:/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@global"
MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
IRBRC:        ""
RUBYOPT:      ""
gemset:       ""
```

My script parse an HTML page and also has to create a file inside the folder it is, write/read to this file and also Libnotify has to set a this i don't know how to exactly explain it but it's some kind of path :

```
Libnotify.icon_dirs << '/home/' + ENV['USER'] + '/Downloads/NotificationIcons/'
```

So maybe one of those is what Ocra means by relative path but I'm not sure a 100% that's why I'd like to understand what 'relative path' explicitly means and also why do I have this stack trace with this error.

PS: The 'xxxx' are just here for privacy !

Thanks for any help in advance I'm currently stuck in packaging my project to cross-platforms for now I'm just trying to get it on Windows.

If you need anymore information just ask for it, also be gentle if I made any mistakes as this is my first question asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: it might be that you need to downgrade ruby or rubygems, From the ocra readme: `Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.3, 2.0.0 and 2.1.5 support` whereas you're using 2.4.  By the way this line `require 'rubygems'` hasn't been necessary since 1.9

Comment: I've got same error here it is with Ruby 2.0.0 `/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ocra-1.3.6/bin/ocra:41:in 'relative_path_from': undefined method 'path' for "/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@global":String (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Also maybe this can help when I run `ocra --version` it give me this warning: `/home/xxxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/ocra-1.3.6/bin/ocra:19: warning: already initialized constant File::ALT_SEPARATOR`
`Ocra 1.3.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocra doesn't work on Linux currently.

Doing a google search for

```
ocra undefined method `path'
```

Linked [here](https://github.com/larsch/ocra/issues/96), an issues page on the Ocra github which shows many people have had the same problem. This in turns links [here](https://github.com/larsch/ocra/issues/98), where the project maintainer says that Ocra does not work on Linux, though it may be worth a shot with Wine.